Playing an audio file before it is fully loaded on the JS page
I'm currently working on the ability to voice text at the click of a button. I have a button that should play text when clicked. I get the audio file through the API after the click, everything works well in this regard, I get the url of the audio file. The problem appears when I try to make this audio work on click. My code now looks something like this:
speech.addEventListener('click', () => {
  let speechText = "Привет!";
  const audio = new Audio();
  const audioURL = await getOpenaiVoice(voiceAPI, voiceID, speechText);
  audio.src = audioURL;
  audio.play();
}

The code waits for the URL to return from getOpenaiVoice and assigns it to audio.src, but then audio.play(); is triggered instantly, which causes an error: NotSupportedError: Failed to load because no supported source was found.
If you click on the button again after a while, the audio will play normally, because it has already been fully uploaded to the site, and there will be no errors.
I tried to rewrite the code with promises, wrap elements in async await, but I have too little knowledge of asynchronous programming for me to immediately see what the problem is. I've been working on this problem all day and I don't see any options.
function audioLoad(audio, url) {
        let prom = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
           audio.src = url;
           audio.addEventListener('loadeddata', () => {
                resolve(audio);
           });
        });
            
        prom.then((value) => {
            value.play();
        })
}
  
async function audioCreation() {
        let speechText = "Привет!";
        const audio = new Audio();
        const audioURL = await getOpenaiVoice(voiceAPI, voiceID, speechText);
        audio.src = audioURL;
        audio.play();
}
        
audioCreation();

The code above works, however, only if you click after the file is fully downloaded. On the first click there are always an error, because it starts downloading only after the click. The general idea is: The user clicks on the voice button, all requests are sent to the API, etc., the code waits for the response to return, and after the response returns, either the audio file starts playing immediately, or it just hangs waiting for full download, and after downloading it starts playing. Thank you in advance.

Waiting for the audio.canplaythrough event before calling audio.play() should take care of the problem.

@Yogi No, when the button is clicked again, new text is generated

@Yogi, Thank you. Yes, it is being used on the backend for voice generation, streaming for real time audio.  Backend uses an Openai Text to Speech API, I use backend API, it sends me an audio's URL that I need to place into the JS code so user can listen the text) getOpenaiVoice is indeed a wrapped function that uses fetch and return url with voiceover.

You need to listen for either the canplay or canplaythrough audio event.
// Added async keyword
speech.addEventListener('click', async () => {
  let speechText = "Привет!";
  const audio = new Audio();
  const audioURL = await getOpenaiVoice(voiceAPI, voiceID, speechText);

  // Added the once option
  audio.addEventListener( "canplaythrough", event => {
    audio.play();
  }, {once: true} )

  // Triggers the canplaythrough event when the audio is done loading
  audio.src = audioURL;
} )


Thank you for your answer, I think it could work, but something in my code works wrong and I noticed that audio.src = audioURL assigns a value right after await getOpenaiVoice function returns an URL. For example, I copied your code and added "console.log(audio)" right after 4th line, before event listener. And it's already returned an audio element with assigned src, although the assignment of the value is a few lines lower...

I just noticed that your click event listener does not have the async keyword. Also the canplaythrough event listener should be set to run only once. I'll edit my code with these changes.

@Igor you probably did not take into account the specific behavior of console.log, when logging objects - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/console#snapshotting_objects
